# C++ Python Module not being linked into Python with g++

Tags: python, linux, gcc, g++, python-2.6

I have a custom C++ Python Module that I want to build into Python that builds fine but fails when it goes to the linking stage. I have determined that the problem is that it is using the gcc to link and not g++ and this is what is causing all of the errors I am seeing when it tries to link in the std libraries. How would I get the Python build process to link with g++ instead of gcc? Do I have to manually edit the Makefile or is it something I need to set when I am configuring it. I am compiling Python 2.6 on CentOS 5.8.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What are you using to configure/build your makefile?

Comment: Have you tried setting your CXX environment variable to g++ ?

Comment: @Xymostech I am just using the configure script that comes with Python2.6

Comment: @jdi I have not tried that yet. I'll give that a shot right now.

Comment: Are you recompiling the entire python interpreter with custom code, or building an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by manually editing the Makefile generated by the configure script so that the linker was using g++ instead of gcc and that solved my problems. Thanks for the possible suggestions!